# How do I submit form data to my Ruby Controller via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, controller

I have a semantic_form_for in my view that sets up a search filter, and more filters are added with a button that, through JavaScript, adds more filters.

```
 <%= semantic_form_for current_coach, :remote => true, :html => { :class => "custom-form rb-form", :id => "filter", :'data-url' => "#{roster_builder_coach_index_path}" } do |f| %>
  <div class="filter_parent_container">
    <% @search.conditions.each do |condition| %>
        <%= render "filter", :condition => condition %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-info">
    <div class="count">
      <p class="num"><%= @athletes.count %></p>
      <p>identified with this filter set</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="send-request" id="search-button" value="" />
    <input type="button" class="add_filter" value="Add Another Filter" />
  </div>
  <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
<% end %>
```

I need the form to submit via ajax, but it isn't. I'm checking the params in the controller and they are:

```
{"action"=>"roster_builder", "controller"=>"coach"}
```

Here's the controller (logger is checking the params):

```
def roster_builder
authorize! :access_roster_builder, current_coach

logger.info("**************");
logger.info("**************");
logger.info("**************");
logger.info("**************");
logger.info("**************");
logger.info(params);
@search = Search.new(sport: current_coach.primary_sport, conditions: params[:search])
@athletes = @search.query.page(params[:page]).per_page(8)

render "athletes" if request.format.js?
end
```

Here is the Ajax call:

```
$("#filter").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: $("#filter").attr("data-url"),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      $(".results")[0].parentNode.removeChild($(".results")[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

Before I used :remote => true, it was working, but I need persistence across the filters (including the ones added via JS), so I need Ajax to perform the search rather than doing a page refresh. Why isn't params working now that Ajax is sending the form data? I even tried sending the data via Ajax as serialized, to no avail, as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $("#filter").attr("data-url"),
  type: 'POST',
  data: $("form#filter").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    $(".results")[0].parentNode.removeChild($(".results")[0]);
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you try handling the errors to at least see what kind of error you are getting. Maybe you could monitor (in the Networking tab of Chrome dev tools) to see if a call is actually fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do not use both `remote: true` AND an ajax call in the submit event of the form.
- If you make the ajax call yourself, then you will definitely need to pass the params with `data: $("form").serialize()`
- You have to return false, or do e.preventDefault() in the submit event, because you don't actually want the form to be submitted, since you're sending the data yourself with the ajax call.
- this plugin to handle ajax forms is great: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Thanks! Took out my JS and simply used remote: true, dumb mistake!